# Rails 2.0.5 with AJAX form error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Below code still do not work ajax. How can I fixed it? 
Using link_to_remote in my project is being okay but form_remote_tag using ajax is just do as normally and do not work ajax. Please Help me. I am using Rails 2.0.5 and Ruby 1.8.6.

```
<% form_remote_tag(:url => url_for(:action => :create001), :update => "stantdard1") do %>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Target</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> <%= text_area_tag :target %> </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <%= submit_tag "save"%>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: can you post the html generated by this?

Comment: Thanks. Generated html is as below.
<form onsubmit="new Ajax.Updater('stantdard1', '/targethome/create001', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.serialize(this)}); return false;" method="post" action="/targethome/create001">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
 <textarea id="target" name="target"></textarea>
</td>
<input class="btn-cyan" type="submit" value="save" name="commit">
</form>

Comment: that looks correct. does your application.js file includes jquery_ujs ?

Comment: Below are javascript files which use at layout file.
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/prototype.js?1392021788">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/effects.js?1392021788">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1392021788">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/controls.js?1392021788">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/application.js?1392021788">

Comment: can you show the contents of application.js ?

Comment: No code on application.js.

Comment: it definetely looks like some js is missing. that kind of behaviour usually is provided by the 'jquery_ujs'. try including it in your layout and it might solve the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47775/discussion-between-julio-elixir-and-andre-barbosa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved above error by using below code because Rails can't call ajax even using form_remote_tag. Then need to write ajax code in javaScript.

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".submitForm").submit(function() {
                $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
                return false;
            });
        }); 
    </script>
```